# Cisco Systems VPN Client 5 on x64

Tags: windows-server-2008, cisco, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have a 64 bit Windows Server 2008 machine that I want to run the Cisco Systems VPN Client 5 on.

It will not run because it says it does not support 32 bit.  Is there a way to fire this off under 32 bit mode?  Is there such a thing as 32 bit mode?

(I know there are similar questions out there, but I read through them and none of them worked for me.)

Comment: Can you explain your situation more detailed? Why did the solutions in http://serverfault.com/questions/5221/64-bit-cisco-vpn-client-ipsec did not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NCP Secure Entry Client will work with an IPSec Cisco VPN.  I loaded the beta version (that has windows 7 support) and imported my .pcf and it worked like a charm!!!!

It costs $144!  (Hope I can get my boss to spring for it.)

Answer (score 3):

The Cisco VPN client is not compatible with 64 bit version of windows. You must use  Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client

Comment: ..and the AnyConnect client doesn't work with IPSec VPN, afaik.. Only SSL VPN.. Which is better, but non-backwards compatible.. :-/

Answer (score 1):

You can also refer to [this entry](https://serverfault.com/questions/5221/64-bit-cisco-vpn-client-ipsec).

They mentionned the [Shrew Soft VPN Client](http://www.shrew.net/) which seems to be good enough to replace the Cisco client.