# Cisco VPN client for WIndows 7 x64

Tags: vpn, cisco, cisco-vpn

Does anyone know what my options are for a Cisco compatible VPN client on Windows 7 x64?

It doesnt look like the standard one is supported on x64 at all (let alone Windows 7) and the Cisco VPN AnyConnect client doesnt seem to be compatible with our router in its current configuration.

Any pointers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Shrew Soft VPN client](http://shrew.net/) is a free IPSec client that runs on 32-bit and 64-bit Windows.

Current stable release (2.1.4) does not list Windows 7 as supported. Latest development version (2.1.5-rc2) should work. 2.1.5 also adds Cisco VPN profile (.pcf file) import, so if you have existing profile files you should try this version.

Similar questions:

- [64-bit Cisco VPN client (IPsec)
  ?](https://serverfault.com/questions/5221/64-bit-cisco-vpn-client-ipsec)
- [Cisco VPN Client for Windows
  Vista](https://serverfault.com/questions/35594/cisco-vpn-client-for-windows-vista)

Comment: Thanks - development version works perfectly! Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you will ever see one.  Cisco has yet to produce a x64 version of the VPN client for Vista either.  My understanding is that development on their VPN client has all but ceased, and they are pushing people towards AnyConnect.  Keep in mind that the PIX line is already EoS (for both hardware and accessories/licenses), and will be going EoL July 27, 2013.

Which Cisco product are you using?

Answer (score 1):

[NCP Secure Entry Client](http://www.ncp-e.com/en/solutions/vpn-products/secure-entry-client.html) should do the trick.  I have not used it in Windows 7 (the maker says it works), but happily use it under Vista 64.  It is a little pricey at $144/client.  If this is for more than a few users, it might make more sense to upgrade your Router/Firewall so you can use the still maintained and supported AnyConnect client from Cisco.

[VPNC](http://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~massar/vpnc/) with the [VPNC Front End](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vpncfe/) works on 64bit Vista according to various web searches.  I have no experience with VPNC under windows, but am happy with it under linux.

Many Cisco Firewall/Routers can be configured to support the built-in l2tp VPN client that Vista has installed by default.  I have connected to this type of setup as a user but know nothing about the setup from the router/firewall side.

Answer (score 0):

NCP Secure Entry Client should do the trick. I have not used it in Windows 7 (the maker says it works), but happily use it under Vista 64. It is a little pricey at $144/client. If this is for more than a few users, it might make more sense to upgrade your Router/Firewall so you can use the still maintained and supported AnyConnect client from Cisco.