# Import PCF file to set up native Windows 7 VPN connection

Tags: networking, windows-7, vpn

I have received a PCF file for a VPN connection from my client to log on into their network.

I am able to use it with the Cisco VPN Client without any problem.

I also noticed there is option in Windows 7 to natively set up a VPN connection. But I cannot figure out how to import the PCF file to it.

Answer (score 6):

The Windows Native VPN client only connects to PPTP, L2TP, and DirectAccess servers. The PCF file you have is for a Cisco VPN. See this question about [Cisco VPN software for Windows 7](https://serverfault.com/questions/5221/64-bit-cisco-vpn-client-ipsec). In particular the [Shewsoft client can open the PCF file and connect](https://serverfault.com/questions/5221/64-bit-cisco-vpn-client-ipsec/15595#15595).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to *import* the `.pcf` file, it's not there yet.

...yet it seems Windows **10** supports L2TP/IPSec:

- with certificate, if you have
- with an existing key

so if you know either of them, the IP address of your server, and relevant authentication info, it seems it's possible to *configure* Windows to use its native VPN client.

Hope you can make this exceptional case work.